# How to send email with attachment (such as image) loaded from database in Java?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-mail

I want to make an email that contains a sender, receiver, and image (as an attachment) and it's loaded from database. How to code for it in Java?

Comment: Haven't you tried any code? Show us your trials.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the image link from your database and add it in the email body.
Refer [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) for a simple example